# RPyC SSH connection

Tags: ssh, server, client, cloud, rpyc

I'm trying to establish a client-server connection using **RPyC** between 2 VM instances on google cloud. I have the following code:

**SERVER side:**

```
import rpyc

class MyService(rpyc.Service):
    def on_connect(self):
        # code that runs when a connection is created
        # (to init the serivce, if needed)
        pass

    def on_disconnect(self):
        # code that runs when the connection has already closed
        # (to finalize the service, if needed)
        pass

    def exposed_get_answer(self): # this is an exposed method
        return 42

    def get_question(self):  # while this method is not exposed
        return "what is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
        from rpyc.utils.authenticators import SSLAuthenticator
        authenticator = SSLAuthenticator("myserver.key", "myserver.cert")
        server = ThreadedServer(MyService, port=12345, authenticator=authenticator)
        server.start()
```

**CLIENT side:**

```
import rpyc

conn = rpyc.ssl_connect("myserver", port = 12345, keyfile=None,
                        certfile=None)
conn.execute("print ('world')")
```

When i run Client.py i get the following error

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

I think that has something to do with the keyfile and certfile, but i'm not sure how to set them. Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**GAIERROR** : **G**et **A**ddress **I**nfo **E**rror

This error comes when the name resolution fails.

Either add entry in `/etc/hosts` file if both machines are Linux
OR replace "myserver" with IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name "myserver" is reachable, otherwise replace it by an IP address.