# plumbum fails to connect via jump host, but raw command succeeds

Tags: python, ssh, plumbum, jumphost

I'm trying to SSH into `final_machine` via the jump host `portal_machine`. Both remote machines are Linux, local is Windows. When I run the following command in a cmd, I can successfully connect

```
ssh {username}@{final_machine} -oProxyCommand="ssh -W {final_machine}:22 {username}@{portal_machine}"
```

And I can also successfully connect through python with

```
ssh_command = plumbum.local["ssh"][f"{username}@{final_machine}", "-o", f"ProxyCommand=ssh -W {final_machine}:22 {username}@{portal_machine}"]
ssh_command()
```

However, I need to connect via an `SshMachine` object for compatibility, and when I try the following, it fails

```
plumbum.SshMachine(final_machine, user=username,
        ssh_opts=[fr'-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W {final_machine}:22 {username}@{portal_machine}"'])
```

with error

```
Return code:  | None
Command line: | 'true '
Host:         | {final machine}
Stderr:       | CreateProcessW failed error:2
```

I've tried replacing `ssh` with `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`, but no change. I have SSH keys set up from my machine to portal_machine, my machine to final_machine, and portal_machine to final_machine. Any other suggestions for how to debug would be appreciated. When I connect simply to the portal machine, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use `ProxyJump` than `ProxyCommand`, and move as many settings as possible into `~/.ssh/config`.

Sample configuration for the mentioned hosts:

```
HOST portal
    HostName portal.machine.host.name.or.IP
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your.portal.key

HOST final
    HostName final.machine.host.name.or.IP
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your.final.key
    ProxyJump portal
```

Tunnel then with:

```py
machine = plumbum.SshMachine('final')
pwd = machine['pwd']
pwd()  # '/home/ec2-user\n'
```

Comment: Hello, a very sensible method, works great, thanks. Apologies for slow reply, was afk over christmas.